# Sending email twice with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, delayed-job

I've seen other questions about this, but I check, and I don't call deliver twice.

This is my mailer

```
class Suggestion < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "me@myapp.com"

  def send_suggest(subject, body, sender, ref)

    @sender = sender
    @body = body
    @ref =ref

    mail(:to => "mail@myapp.com", :subject => "#{subject} from #{sender}" )
  end
end
```

this gets sent from the suggestion controller

```
def create 

        if (!current_user.nil?)

            sender = current_user.email

        end
        subject = params[:subject]
        body = params[:description]
        Suggestion.delay.send_suggest(subject, body, sender, request.referer)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js { render :nothing => true }  
        end
    end
```

as you can see, `delay` gets called once. I can see with foreman, that the worker handles the email.

to further investigate this.. I changed `delay` to `delay(queue: "Suggestions", priority: 20, run_at: 5.minutes.from_now)`

and after 5 minutes, I would recieve 2 email. So sending the email gets delayed. but then sends it twice
The email is sent twice. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem earlier and found this question. This was the solution (for my issue).

Check that the number of delayed job workers you have running.

ps -ef | grep delayed_job

```
root     18848     1  0 Aug27 ?        00:23:24 delayed_job
root     20104     1  0 Aug26 ?        00:23:54 delayed_job
root     21805     1  0 Aug27 ?        00:23:15 delayed_job
```

Then stop the specific process (if calling script/delayed_job stop fails)

kill -9 18848